# How to properly update xlwings

Tags: xlwings

After xlwings is updated from `0.6` to `0.7.0`, I have the following problem.

**Although xlwings works**, when I click **Import Python UDFs**, I get an error that tells:

> Run-time error '1004' Cannot run the macro...

The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

*Xlwings* web site only tells about installation of the package. I could not see steps for upgrading the package.

What is the proper way of upgrading *xlwings*? What should be the steps for the upgrade?

Answer (score 4):

The python package itself is updated like every other package (`pip install --upgrade xlwings` or `conda upgrade xlwings`).

Updating the Excel add-in is explained [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/command_line.html#add-in-currently-windows-only), the easiest way is to run `xlwings addin update`.

However, this expects that you have also installed the add-in previously with `xlwings addin install`. If not, you could also update it manually by replacing your current version (wherever that is saved) with the latest version that is in the xlwings package (run `>>> import xlwings`, `>>> xlwings.__path__` to see where the xlwings package has been installed).

By the way, I assume you're facing [this issue](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/331) that had been fixed with v0.6.4

Comment: I installed the new version, 0.7.0 and then updated the addin but i still have this error. Should i first install 0.6.4 and then install 0.7.0 in order to overcome this problem?

Comment: Make sure that the xlwings module in VBA is also v0.7.0 - that part I guess I forgot to mention in the answer. An this part you have to do manually.

Comment: As soon as i made that update (and removed old ones), i can no longer call my python functions. #VALUE! is written in the cell that i call the python function. Sorry to take your time but this is really a mess. :(

Comment: I forgot to mention that pip is not an option for me as i am behind the company proxy (pip's proxy options dont work either) so i installed the package with "python setup.py install".

Comment: You need to reimport the UDFs after updating. `python setup.py install` should work just fine, but you can also do `pip install C:\path\to\xlwings-0.7.0.tar.gz`

Comment: actually i did install with that command and then copied xlwings32.dll to the python installation path. I imported .bas module. I updated the addin with "xlwings addin update". Do i miss anything here? For one python function, i dont get any return; excel cell has #VALUE!. For another python function, i have "Unexpected Python Error: Memory ErrorÇ CreatingSafeArray" All of these worked perfectly before all of these upgrade steps.

Comment: Can you please open an issue on GitHub. This is getting to long for SO.

Answer (score 0):

you must install and upgrade the version before to install addin, dont works if you do not upgrade